# Issue with Paper size in java

Tags: java, printing

I have using code to print something on paper using printer i have used following code for fixing paper size but it seems not working. I still have to adjust size in print dialogue .I want to adjust size in code it self not in print dialog .

```
 Paper paper = new Paper();
      double paperWidth = 3;//3.25
      double paperHeight = 5;//11.69
      double leftMargin = 0.12;
      double rightMargin = 0.10;
      double topMargin = 0.75;
      double bottomMargin = 0.01;

      paper.setSize(paperWidth * 100, paperHeight * 100);
      paper.setImageableArea(leftMargin * 200, topMargin * 200,
           (paperWidth - leftMargin - rightMargin) * 200,
           (paperHeight - topMargin - bottomMargin) * 200));
```

Comment: Paper paper = new Paper();
          double paperWidth = 3;//3.25
          double paperHeight = 5;//11.69
          double leftMargin = 0.12;
          double rightMargin = 0.10;
          double topMargin = 0.75;
          double bottomMargin = 0.01;

          paper.setSize(paperWidth * 100, paperHeight * 100);
          paper.setImageableArea(leftMargin * 200, topMargin * 200,
               (paperWidth - leftMargin - rightMargin) * 200,
               (paperHeight - topMargin - bottomMargin) * 200));`enter code here`
    enter code here

Comment: Please paste your code in your question not in comments